# Eclipse says there is a syntax error on a line that has no letters in a JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to make a JSP that deletes entries from a database, but it's giving me a syntax error where the only thing on the line is `<%`. There is no red underline, only the red circle with the x in it next to the line number. I used code from this  [tutorial](https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/delete-data-from-database.shtml), and I'm fairly sure that I don't have any typos. Here is the code that I have:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="PlaygroundDeleteSuccess.jsp">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Enter the Equipment ID you wish to delete:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="id">
</td>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<%! String driverName = "org.postgresql.Driver"; %>
<%! String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.235:5432/postgres"; %>
<%! String user = "postgres"; %>
<%! String pass = "password"; %>
<%
String id = request.getParameter("id");

if (id != null) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    int equipID = Integer.parseInt(id);
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        String sql = "DELETE FROM playground WHERE equip_id = " + equipID;
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        int i = ps.executeUpdate();

        if (i >0) {
        %>
        <jsp:forward page="/PlaygroundDeleteSuccess.jsp"/>
        <%
        } else {
        %>
        <jsp:forward page="/PlaygroundDeleteFail.jsp"/>
        <% //This is the line that the red circle with the x show up on
        }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            request.setAttribute("error", e);
            out.println(e);
        }
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

And the stacktrace from when I try to visit the page:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [196] in the generated java file: [C:\JavaEE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\G2\org\apache\jsp\Pages\PlaygroundDelete_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement

An error occurred at line: [196] in the generated java file: [C:\JavaEE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\G2\org\apache\jsp\Pages\PlaygroundDelete_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

An error occurred at line: [213] in the generated java file: [C:\JavaEE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\G2\org\apache\jsp\Pages\PlaygroundDelete_jsp.java]
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

An error occurred at line: [214] in the generated java file: [C:\JavaEE\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\G2\org\apache\jsp\Pages\PlaygroundDelete_jsp.java]
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:473)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:362)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:346)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

When I hover over the red circle, it says:

```
 Multiple annotations found at this line:    
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody    
    - Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete IfStatement   
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
    - Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

EDIT: Now for some reason whenever I refresh the page, it sometimes loads and sometimes throws the same 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look properly... 
your try{ } catch { } block is within if { } 
so u havent closed ur if  closing  brace that will come after closing brace of catch.